# Uploading an Air app to the Google store

Tags: actionscript-3, intellij-idea, air, google-play, apk

I never uploaded anything to the google store, and after finishing my app (250mbs) I've realized that it needs to be 50mbs top, and then to add separate files for assets.

How does this work exactly?, I'm packaging the Air app using iNtellij IDEA, I didn't see any options to make different packages or anything like that.

Answer (score 1):

You need to store your external assets somewhere (such as Amazon S3 servers) and create your own in app functionality to download and store the assets when the app is launched for the first time.

So: Create an app that is 50mb max.
The app is downloaded onto the device and is launched.
It checks to see if the large assets have been downloaded onto the device. If not, you begin the download procedure, storing the assets to the device memory.

I've created an AIR app which does a similar thing which you can see in action. Download the app and tap Workouts.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=air.com.sm4business.primemover

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to read about [JOBB](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/jobb.html) and [APK Expansion Files](http://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html)

I also found [this blog post](http://www.aymericlamboley.fr/blog/belle-et-sebastien-fighting-androids-apk-50mb-limit/) (non official) talking about some solutions that may be useful.

- Check this [Native Extension](https://gumroad.com/l/cbHe) (I haven't tried, also, it's not free)